# Trying to match both subdomain and path with a RewriteRule, getting only the subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm doing some tests in a local project (using vHosts). I've managed to create a RewriteRule to redirect `something.kensaku.com` to `www.kensakuapp.com/something`, but I'd like to redirect `something.kensaku.com/myapp` to `www.kensakuapp.com/something/myapp`.

My rewrite rule is this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.kensaku.com
RewriteRule ^(^.*) goto.php?username=%1&path=$1
```

I have been trying it for hours and I still can't manage to get the `/myapp` part. If I go to `something.kensaku.com/myapp`, `$1` will match `goto.php`, but shouldn't it match `/myapp`?

Here's the content of the `goto.php` script I use for the redirection:

```
<?php 
$user = $_GET['username'];
header("Location: http://www.kensakuapp.com/$user/".$_GET['path']); 
?>
```

If there are other ways to do it without using PHP I'll be thankful to know it — but if it's possible I'd like to keep using the PHP method because in future perhaps I'll want to add tracking or logging features to it.

If I missed anything on the question, please tell me!

**EDIT:** Logs for rewritemod, trace 3:

```
[Wed Mar 20 19:26:28.624291 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 24190] mod_rewrite.c(467): [client 127.0.0.1:52996] 127.0.0.1 - - [www.kensaku.com/sid#982bb28][rid#9a7d120/initial] [perdir /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/] pass through /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/
[Wed Mar 20 19:26:28.624352 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 24190] mod_rewrite.c(467): [client 127.0.0.1:52996] 127.0.0.1 - - [www.kensaku.com/sid#982bb28][rid#9a7b118/subreq] [perdir /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/] pass through /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/index.html
[Wed Mar 20 19:26:28.624402 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 24190] mod_rewrite.c(467): [client 127.0.0.1:52996] 127.0.0.1 - - [www.kensaku.com/sid#982bb28][rid#9a7b118/subreq] [perdir /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/] pass through /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/index.html.var
[Wed Mar 20 19:26:28.624434 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 24190] mod_rewrite.c(467): [client 127.0.0.1:52996] 127.0.0.1 - - [www.kensaku.com/sid#982bb28][rid#9a7b118/subreq] [perdir /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/] pass through /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/index.php
[Wed Mar 20 19:26:28.630172 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 24190] mod_rewrite.c(467): [client 127.0.0.1:52996] 127.0.0.1 - - [www.kensaku.com/sid#982bb28][rid#9a7f2f0/initial] [perdir /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/] strip per-dir prefix: /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/ -> 
[Wed Mar 20 19:26:28.630202 2013] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 24190] mod_rewrite.c(467): [client 127.0.0.1:52996] 127.0.0.1 - - [www.kensaku.com/sid#982bb28][rid#9a7f2f0/initial] [perdir /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/] applying pattern '^.+$' to uri ''
[Wed Mar 20 19:26:28.630216 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 24190] mod_rewrite.c(467): [client 127.0.0.1:52996] 127.0.0.1 - - [www.kensaku.com/sid#982bb28][rid#9a7f2f0/initial] [perdir /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/] pass through /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/
[Wed Mar 20 19:26:28.630277 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 24190] mod_rewrite.c(467): [client 127.0.0.1:52996] 127.0.0.1 - - [www.kensaku.com/sid#982bb28][rid#9a7b118/subreq] [perdir /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/] pass through /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/index.html
[Wed Mar 20 19:26:28.630327 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 24190] mod_rewrite.c(467): [client 127.0.0.1:52996] 127.0.0.1 - - [www.kensaku.com/sid#982bb28][rid#9a7b118/subreq] [perdir /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/] pass through /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/index.html.var
[Wed Mar 20 19:26:28.630360 2013] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 24190] mod_rewrite.c(467): [client 127.0.0.1:52996] 127.0.0.1 - - [www.kensaku.com/sid#982bb28][rid#9a7b118/subreq] [perdir /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/] pass through /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku/index.php
```

**EDIT 2**: Here are the vHosts:

```
# Kensaku Domains
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@kensaku.com
   DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensaku
   ServerName kensaku.com   
   ServerAlias *.kensaku.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@kensaku.com
   DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/kensakuapp
   ServerName kensakuapp.com   
   ServerAlias *.kensakuapp.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Enable logging with `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` and post the relevant logs.

Comment: The log has been taken attempting to go to `www.kensaku.com` using Olaf's rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need PHP here.

Just capture the needed parts in a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and use them in the substitution

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.kensaku\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.kensakuapp.com/%1/$0 [R,L]
```

This captures `something` in the RewriteCond in `%1` and `myapp` in the RewriteRule in `$0`.

Comment: As the `www.kensaku.com` should also redirect to `kensakuapp.com/www`, I can remove the first RewriteCond, can't I?

Comment: Also it won't work — going to `www.kensaku.com` gave me a redirection loop error...

Comment: Yes to your first comment. I just tested this again and `olaf.kensaku.com/test` redirects to `www.kensakuapp.com/olaf/test`, same for `www.kensaku.com/tast` which redirects to `www.kensakuapp.com/www/tast`. No loop here. Do you have other rules in your .htaccess or server config, which could cause this?

Comment: No, I don't have any other rules neither in the htacces nor in the httpd.conf....

Comment: @AddisonMontgomery I modified the rule to capture the root dir as well. I reread your question and I think, I missed some fact the first time. Do you have two separate virtual hosts? One for `*.kensaku.com` and one for `www.kensakuapp.com`?

Comment: *EDIT* No, I don't. I appended the vhosts to the question.

Comment: Oh, I don't know what made it work, but I added a separate vHost for `www.kensaku.com` and updated the .htaccess with your updated one, and it works now! Thanks, thanks, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your logs I'm not entirely sure, but my first guess is that you need to add the pass-through flag (`[PT]`) to your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /goto.php?username=%1&path=$1 [PT]
```

In addition to the `PT` flag, I've removed the erroneous double `^` in your rule and I've made the path to `goto.php` explicit (which may or not be required but is probably good practice). Regarding the `PT` flag, remember this from the `mod_rewrite` documentation:

> By default, mod_rewrite maps a URL to a filesystem path.

The target of your rewrite (`goto.php?...`) is not a filesystem path, so you need it further  processed by Apache.  The `passthrough` flag is what does this:

> Forces the resulting URI to be passed back to the URL mapping engine for processing of other URI-to-filename translators, such as Alias or Redirect.

If this doesn't solve things, post your logs as requested and we can take a closer look